# Boostrap element overflowing its container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a simple design with a navbar and two side by side wells, but the wells are not aligning with their container, overflowing it horizontally to the right (screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/adcWx.jpg)

I'd also like the wells to fit the screen height, but currently they overflow vertically making the user have to scroll down.

Here's my code, JSFiddle renders it differently from Firefox (link to screenshot above), fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/vrk3vcxb/

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> One
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>            
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li onclick="#">
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Four</a>
        </li>
         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Five
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="well">

        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">      
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xl" role="group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> Nine</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ten</button>
        </div>
        <div class="well">

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

</div> <!-- top container -->


</body>
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `height:100vh`  wells to fit the screen height. and can you elaborate more what you want ?

Comment: "the wells are not aligning with their container, overflowing it horizontally to the right"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the wells height you can use, as already suggested VH, or flexbox if no need to support explorer < 9. 
As for the grid, you have a nested container class giving an extra padding, your code should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> One
        <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>            
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li onclick="#">
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Four</a>
    </li>
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Five
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="well">

    </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">      
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xl" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> Nine</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ten</button>
    </div>
    <div class="well">

    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/owpYEG?editors=1100

Comment: Yes, that container wrapping the row was causing this, I was expecting the container to simply fit it's parent element. Are the buttons meant to not have any margins (they're "glued" to the well) or is it recommended to just separate these elements into further rows? Thanks.

Comment: I would rather add my own custom wrapper with a bottom margin, rows can give unwanted padding and screw up again your grid.

Comment: The wells are still overflowing using style="height: 100vh;" (perhaps because the navbar takes vertical space?), is there a standard way, e.g. using containers, to make the whole content just fit the screen vertically so the user doesn't need to scroll? Thanks.

Comment: uhm, the problem is that bootstrap divs use float. You may try to use flexbox (bootstrap 4 has already support for that), or some javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Better to remove 'container' class just above the 'row' class, it will help the overflowing to right.
For the wells to fit the screen height just add some styles: `height:100vh`

Comment: The wells are still overflowing using style="height: 100vh;" (perhaps because the navbar takes vertical space?), is there a standard way, e.g. using containers, to make the whole content just fit the screen vertically so the user doesn't need to scroll? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this [code](https://codepen.io/divyapanackal/pen/dRJQbm). I just hide the top right buttons and added a height to the class 'well'.

Comment: style="height: calc(100vh - 150px);" prevents the well from overflowing, but then both wells aren't aligned at the bottom (i.e. they don't look like they are contained by the same element). My objective was to use the <row> to fill its container from top to bottom and everything within the <row> (the wells) would be naturally aligned and scrolling whenever necessary.

Comment: Actually, manually specifying a height like  this causes the contents of the well to overflow it

Answer (score 1):

To fix you're overflowing well you might wanna add it into a `col`... In the fiddle you had it placed outside the `col-md-4 div`...

As you add content to the wells they should vertically fill the page... you could always add some `padding` I would also recommend using a separate CSS file and removing the inline styles.

If you need more help let me know and ill amend my answer for you.

```
<body>

<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->


      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></span> Scans
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Scan files</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">See previous scans</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li onclick="#">
            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Help</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> Account
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Send feedback</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Upgrade account</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="well">
        <div id="dText" style="background: white; height: 85%; overflow-y:auto; padding:10px;" ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-xl" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span> Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward" aria-hidden="true"></span> Next</button>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <div id="dText2" style="background: white; height: 85%; overflow-y:auto; padding:10px;" ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- top container -->


</body>

</html>
```

You also have a `container` wrapping the whole thing... But then inside your `navbar` you have a `container-fluid` Try and write the whole thing yourself from scratch... use the bootstarp documentaion for a referance

Comment: "As you add content to the wells they should vertically fill the page" -> Yes, they do, but they don't fit the display area perfectly. I added a scrollable <div> and it does fill the page, but it overflows the screen by a few px (even being scrollable) making the user scroll down to see the bottom of the well's content. Is this behaviour by design, should I just force a height on the element?

Comment: "In the fiddle you had it placed outside the col-md-4 div" -> that was a mistake on copy/pasting the fiddle, the overflowing was due to a superfluous <container>